# RSelenium - rsDriver not connecting to remote server

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

Trying to do some webscraping.

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 9515L, phantomver = NULL, extraCapabilities = list(`chromeOptions` = list(binary = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe")))
```

When I run this code I get this ouput:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$id
[1] NA
```

[This is how my chromedriver looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esJCe.jpg)

My java version is from here:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk20-windows

Why am I getting NA? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider one of the following approaches :

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "my_url.com"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)
```

or

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

url <- "my_url.com"
port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(port = port)
remDrPJS <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = port)
remDrPJS$open()
remDrPJS$navigate(url)
```